# How to get Column value using Microsoft graph api

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a custom column with choice values and assigned a value to Document uploaded in sharepoint as shown in below image
[image]

I can get file details using below code but I am not getting 'Document Status' field in output.

```
  item_path = 'General/xxxxxx-0749.pdf'
  item_url = urllib.parse.quote(item_path)
  prop = urllib.parse.quote('Document Status')
  url = f'{RESOURCE_URL}{API_VERSION}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{item_url}?$expand={prop}'
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  print(response.status_code)
  print(response.text)
```

Both 'Expand' and 'select' is giving below error

```
"code":"BadRequest","message":"Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Term 'Document Status' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression."
```

is there a way to get such custom column values using graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET request returns information about `driveItem`. Drive item has relationship to `listItem` and if you expand `listItem` you will get information about `listItem` including fields which represents the values of the columns set in the list item

```
url = f'{RESOURCE_URL}{API_VERSION}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{item_url}?$expand=listitem'
```

If you want to return only selected fields try this

```
url = f'{RESOURCE_URL}{API_VERSION}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{item_url}?&expand=listitem(expand=fields(select={prop}))
```

Not sure but if the column name contains space then space should be replaced by `_x0020_`

`Document Status` => `Document_x0020_Status`

Resources:

[driveItem relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships)

[listItem relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships)

Comment: Thanks `?$expand=listItem($expand=fields($select=DocumentStatus))` helped in getting desired result